# jqGrid has empty space under last row after sort

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sorting, jqgrid

I'm experiencing a weird issue with sorting the jqGrid. When I sort descending, I have extra space after the last row, however when I sort ascending, the row ends at the bottom of the table and doesn't allow me to scroll further.

I've attached pictures of the issue and a snippet of the html. If someone could point me in the right direction on where I might look to solve the problem, or possible attributes that might be related. Thanks.

I'm taking this project over from a developer who has left our team, I'm a bit inexperienced with jqGrid, but I believe this is the correct version we're using.

jqGrid version : 
jqGrid 4.10.1-pre - free jqGrid: https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid

```
<whql:jqGrid runat="server" ID="CycleSelectGrid" Width="725" Multiselect="true" Scroll="true" DefaultSortCol="DTMPoolID" Sortorder="desc">
```

[image: Gap]
[image: No Gap]
[image: Attributes]

Comment: It's important to post information about the **version** of jqGrid which you use (or can use) and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). A lot of bugs of old versions are fixed in the later versions. Another common problem is the exact usage of jqGrid (the options and callbacks). You should post **JavaScript** code which you use or better to provide the demo, which reproduces the problem. It seems that you use `scroll: 1`, which is not recommended.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've taken over this project from a developer who has left our team and I have little experience with the jqGrid. I believe the version we're using is "jqGrid 4.10.1-pre". I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! "jqGrid 4.10.1-pre" means just one preliminary state of development between 4.10.0 and 4.11.0. I'd strictly recommend you to update to the current 4.13.4 version, which should be full compatible with your exiting code based on "jqGrid 4.10.1-pre". It's important that you post the options, which you use to create jqGrid. How many total rows are in the dataset, which you need to display? Which `datatype` you use?

Comment: Anywhere from 0 - 3000+ rows, looks like we display 20 rows, as we scroll, the next 20 are generated and so on. Datatype = json

Comment: Do you use "virtual scrolling" (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`)? It's one from the options, which I support in free jqGrid because of compatibility reasons, but which I **don't recommend**. It has a lot of restrictions and implementation problems. I suppose that your main problem is the usage of virtual scrolling. **The pictures, which you posted, shows that the width of rows is different*in your grids.** Virtual scrolling can't work correct in the case.

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 4000 rows or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) ith 5000 rows, which shows the performance of **local** paging, sorting and filtering.  You can see the time in ms. It's the recommended way instead of virtual scrolling.

Comment: scroll: true. I'm looking at the examples you've provided. I'm updating the jqgrid as we speak. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The pictures, which you posted, shows that the grid has **variable height** of rows. Moreover it looks like you use virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`). **Virtual scrolling can't work correct in the case.**

I strictly recommend you to update to the current version of free jqGrid (4.13.4) and to use the standard paging instead of virtual paging. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 5000 rows of data in 13 columns and 25 rows in a page. It shows the performance of sorting, paging and filtering of such set of data. You can see that all works quickly. You use `loadonce: true` option, then you use local sorting/paging/filtering too.